# Strange gap off screen that's adding bottom scroll bar

Tags: css, browser, width, screen-size

This is very strange and I'm pretty sure it's to do with some sort of width issue in CSS, but as you start to re-size the browser, it adds this strange gap to the right (Which is off screen).

[Here is the page in question](http://test.snowflakesoftware.com/markets/inspire/)

I've tried looking through the CSS and I can't exactly find anything, I keep going over and over it but it's not sticking out to me.

The website is WordPress driven, so most of the CSS is in **theme.css** and **lessframework.css**. The Sidebar is a fixed width at 202px and the Content is next to it, which has different width sizes based on what screen size. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with that but I just need a second opinion/set of eyes!

Can anybody help?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Here on StackOverflow, you're supposed to 'accept' answers by clicking the checkmark next to an answer if it's correct. You should go back through your questions and check off the ones that have been answered. You're more likely to get a response on new questions if you do that.

Comment: Oh I see! That's probably why it's come up! Just new to Stackoverflow, haven't had a chance to go through it all yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope im not bringing an old question back to life, but i find Firefox's developer tools have been invaluable in ascertaining, on-the-fly, what elements are actually displaying.

The easiest way is to right click on the area in question, and choose the last option 'Inspect Element'. This will open up the source and CSS console and displays the elements current id/class and style.

To go one better, once the console is open, click on the 3D box icon on the right of the console bar to make Firefox render the page in 3D, which will allow you to spin and zoom in on the affected area.